# Pyomo 6.0 on WinPython 3940: best way to install Ipopt?

Tags: pyomo, ipopt

There is no "pip install ipopt".
What is the best way to proceed then, once I installed Pyomo?
I dropped a copy of Ipopt.exe in the  "python-3.9.4.amd64"  forlder, and it works.
But it looks a bit dirty to me!

I use Pyomo since a long time, and installing Ipopt or Glpk has always been an uncertainty.
On colab, azure notebooks, and now winpython.

Thanks

Michel

Answer (score 1):

Place the .exe somewhere and make sure to add the directory to the PATH. The same goes for glpk.

The python folder you mentioned is probably on the system's path and that’s why it works.